# Django rest framework custom ordering field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have enabled ordering on my API, and it works just fine. My problem is that it only allows me to order by fields values. I want to be able to make a query like

```
GET /api/some_endpoint/?crazy_query=123
```

and then, even though the model has no field `crazy_field`, I want to be able to respond to it somehow. I just don't know where do do it. The `OrderingFilter` is currently injected into all my viewsets by use of setting `DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS`. I guess I would have to create a custom filter backend, but I'm unsure how to go about it

Comment: What do you mean by "custom ordering field" and how your API should respond for that exact query?

Comment: I simply mean that query parameters may not necessarily map 1-to-1 with model fields, fx. with `search`, `q`, `ordering`, etc. I wish to know where I can implement logic for such a parameter within the DRF

Comment: Good place for that logic will be custom filter backend. You can also put that logic directly into your view. If it's all about filtering or ordering your result, filter backend will be best choice.

Comment: @GwynBleidD I did think of the view, but as you say, it is better suited to a filter backend. Could you provide an example of how to create such a backend?

Answer (score 4):

You can add your custom filter backend class anywhere you like. E.g. in

restframework_filters/CrazyBackend.py:

```
class CrazyBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    """
    My crazy filter.
    """
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        crazy = request.query_params.get('crazy_query', None)
        if crazy:
            queryset = queryset.filter(...something crazy...)
        return queryset
```

Then add it to the settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'restframework_filters.CrazyBackend', ...
    ),
```

Don't forget the empty __init__.py in the new folder.

Comment: For anyone looking now `request.QUERY_PARAMS` has been deprecated in favor of `request.query_params`