# Django Rest Ordering custom

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm using django rest framework and I would like to order with a custom method.

So, when I call this url for example : http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sets/?ordering=partMissing

It's possible to call a custom method because I would like to order with the number of part missing by snippet. I made count the sum of number of part in the many to many field.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have very simple POC, that should allow you to implement more sophisticated solution.

`views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from ordering_test.models import Test
from ordering_test.ordering import MyCustomOrdering
from ordering_test.serializers import TestSerializer

class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
    filter_backends = (MyCustomOrdering,)
```

`ordering.py`:

```
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter

class MyCustomOrdering(OrderingFilter):

    allowed_custom_filters = ['testMethod']

    def get_ordering(self, request, queryset, view):
        """
        Ordering is set by a comma delimited ?ordering=... query parameter.

        The `ordering` query parameter can be overridden by setting
        the `ordering_param` value on the OrderingFilter or by
        specifying an `ORDERING_PARAM` value in the API settings.
        """
        params = request.query_params.get(self.ordering_param)

        if params:
            fields = [param.strip() for param in params.split(',')]
            # care with that - this will alow only custom ordering!
            ordering = [f for f in fields if f in self.allowed_custom_filters]
            if ordering:
                return ordering

        # No ordering was included, or all the ordering fields were invalid
        return self.get_default_ordering(view)

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):

        ordering = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)
        if ordering:
            # implement a custom ordering here
            ordering = ['-id']

        if ordering:
            return queryset.order_by(*ordering)

        return queryset
```

The `models.py` and `serializers.py` are straightforward, but I will still include them here:

`models.py`:

```py
from django.db import models

class Test(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    test1 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

`serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from ordering_test.models import Test

class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('test', 'test1')
```

Happy coding!

Comment: I just leave this here, as this is what I was looking for: foreign key lookup ... https://gist.github.com/sainipray/750820b6ece1f81e022cbab56e68174c

Comment: This no longer works in Django 4.0

Comment: @AdrianGonzalez Guess, I need to update it then :)

Comment: @opalczynski I ended up using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32860854/6929045 it works quite well and you can also import it to a filter_backends in your views.py.

Comment: I modified this by annotating the queryset with a custom field to order by at `# implement a custom ordering here`, and I didn't need to override `get_ordering` at all. Works in Django 4.1

Answer (score 3):

I think a much easier approach to opalczynski's solution would be to introduce a new field for custom ordering:

```
from django import forms

import django_filters
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import MyModel


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field1',)


class CustomOrderingFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    order_by = django_filters.BooleanFilter(
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
        method='filter_order_by',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [
            'order_by'
        ]

    def filter_order_by(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value:
            return self.Meta.model.objects.filter(
                id__in=queryset.values_list('id', flat=True)
            ).order_by(value)

        return queryset

class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    filter_class = CustomOrderingFilter
```

Then you can easily order by any field you want like this: `example.com/api/mymodel/?order_by=partMissing`.

In my example, I used a fixed model field, but you can change the way you order in the `filter_order_by` method on the `CustomOrderingFilter`. Just change it to the logic you want, but make sure to use the `.filter(=queryset.values_list('id', flat=True))` to ensure that other filters that are set, are being used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FilterSet` to annotate and then `OrderingFilter` to order accordingly. As an advantage you may use the `OrderingField` syntax and can still order by multiple fields ad the same time.

- `/api/?annotate_related={id}&order=subscribed`
- `/api/?annotate_related={id}&order=-subscribed`
- `/api/?annotate_related={id}&order=-subscribed,-modified`

FilterSet:

```
class YourFilterSet(FilterSet):
    annotate_related = filters.NumberFilter(method="_annotate_related")

    class Meta:
        model = Model

    def _annotate_related(self, queryset, key, value, *args, **kwargs):
        # eg. annotate if user belongs to a certain category
        return queryset.annotate(is_subscribed=Case(When(annotate_related__id=value, then=1), output_field=IntegerField(), default=0))
```

ViewSet:

```
class YourViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Model.objects.all()
    filterset_class = YourFilterSet
    filter_backends = [OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]
    ordering_fields = [
        "is_subscribed", # order by annotated field
    ]
```