# Django Rest API ordering filters for custom serializer method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-filter, django-filters

I will ordering product in "total_price" values. But my database does not contain a "total_price" value. I then produce in serializer like this:

```
total_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_total_price')
def get_total_price(self,instance):
    price = instance.sell_price - instance.discount_price
    return price
```

my rest api class:

```
    class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
        serializer_class = ProductSerializer
        filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter]
        ...
        ordering_fields = ['created_date', 'sell_price'...]
        ...
```

My error page:

```
FieldError at /api/product/
Cannot resolve keyword 'total_price' into field. Choices are:sell_price,discount_price ....
```

Comment: You just can order by model fields. Or use custom ordering fields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883575/custom-ordering-in-django

Comment: Try using `extra` as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40950745/12601926)